# Laravel access collection elements within another iterator

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, laravel-collection

I have db table `LovColumnComments` and it contains:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| id | view          | column       | description  |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | my_view       | object_id    | Object ID    |
| 2  | my_view       | description  | Description  |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I have another table `DataTable` that contains actual data.

```
-------------------------------------
| id |  object_id    | description  |
-------------------------------------
| 1  |  OBJ_01       | Object 01    |
| 2  |  OBJ_02       | Object 02    |
-------------------------------------
```

Both these tables are passed to the blade view as collections.

Blade template I have right now is:

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        @foreach ($columns as $column)
          <th>{{$column->description}}</th>
        @endforeach
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach ($data as $datum)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$datum['object_id']}}</td>
          <td>{{$datum['description']}}</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to know whether can I access `$data` collection instead of using `$datum['object_id']` and `$datum['description']`. This is because, `DataTable` can be any db table so that field names can be be different but always there will be two columns.

Therefore, `$data` collection will always have two columns, but column names can be different. I need a more dynamic way of getting column names out of `$columns` collection.

Something like, `<td>{{$columns[0]}}</td>` and `<td>{{$columns[1]}}</td>`

FYI, `column` of `$columns` contains the actual names (i.e. `object_id` and `description`)

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to use php's default function: `array_keys()`, then iterating through it inside of your foreach loop

Comment: if I use `$data->toArray()[0]['object_id']`, I am hardcoding `object_id`. I need it to be dynamic so that I do not have to edit the code based on the contents in `$data` collection.

Comment: Yeah, sorry... I saw that an deleted my comment

Comment: As derek says, you should use array_keys

Comment: @LakmalPremaratne please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my example of how I would do this in my blade view:

```
@if(count($data) > 0)
    @php
        $keys = array_keys($data[0]);
    @endphp
    @foreach($data as $d)
        @foreach($keys as $key)
            <!-- This is the dynamic value that works with any array -->
            {{$d[$key]}}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Let me know if you have any questions, I will happily try and help!

Comment: Thanks Derek. I finally got it working. I posted it as an answer. But your previous answer was a 'seed' for my solution...

Comment: @LakmalPremaratne okay, check this one as answer please :)

Comment: I didn't try your answer since my solution works as expected. Thank you for your effort in answering my question. You all are very helpful. Suppose I was not expressive enough in phrasing my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($data as $datum)
  <tr>
    @foreach ($columns as $column)
      <td>{{$datum[$column->column]}}</td>
    @endforeach
  </tr>
@endforeach
```